# SQL Server CE - does it matter if columns within the insert statement are not in the same order as the table itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-insert

Does it matter if columns within the insert statement are not in the same order as the table itself?

**NameTable**

```
firstName | lastName | age |
```

**INSERT** statement:

```
INSERT INTO NameTable (age, firstName, lastName) VALUES (25, 'jane', 'doe');
```

Answer (score 7):

It **doesn't matter at all** as long as you supply correct values (*data type*, etc) on that column.

Comment: @Meowbits I think you have taken a little longer than shortly lol